# Overwrite Object Title in Attachment Layout

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to overwrite the "Object Title" within the Attachment Layout? I am able to attach an image reference, description, and other properties via custom action properties. The only thing which doesn't seem to work is the title. Is there anyway to do this?

What I can do:

```
/me/outside_limits:play?sporting_event=someurl/football.html&image=sample.jpg&result=win&opponent=Tongonoxie&myscore=18&theirscore=12&access_token=...
```

What I would like to do:

```
/me/outside_limits:play?sporting_event=someurl/football.html&title=some_custom_title_here&image=sample.jpg&result=win&opponent=Tongonoxie&myscore=18&theirscore=12&access_token=...
```

Here's an image for reference to the "Attachment Layout"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't override it. You specify the title on the `someurl/football.html` page with the `og:title` meta tag. The idea is that people should see the title of the thing they're clicking on (since the link takes them to the url of the object).